# pchisq increase decimal accurancy

Tags: r, static, statistics

Is there any way to increase the decimal accuracy for probability
distributions.

```
> 1-pchisq(90, 5)
[1] 0
```

But:

```
> pchisq(90, 5, lower.tail=F)
[1] 6.71932e-18
```

Comment: Based on the comments below, you probably need to read up on floating-point accuracy (see e.g. FAQ 7.31 in the R FAQ). There are ways to do computations at higher precision (e.g. `gmp` package) but it's usually best to re-think your problem a bit -- this is why e.g. the `lower.tail` argument exists in the first place ...

Answer (score 4):

If you are doing the `1 - foo` to get the upper tail of the distribution, then don't. Instead use the `lower.tail` argument:

```
> pchisq(90, 5, lower.tail = FALSE)
[1] 6.719319e-18
```

Comment: Thanks but doining this 1- 6.7e-18 =1

Comment: Also check out the `log.p` argument in `?pchisq`

Comment: Well, as far as the computer is concerned, the value shown above is effectively 0 given floating point arithmetic: Try `all.equal(pchisq(90, 5, lower.tail = FALSE), 0)`

Comment: hint: `.Machine$double.neg.eps`