# more significant digits

Tags: r, significant-digits

How can I get more significant digits in R? Specifically, I have the following example:

```
> dpois(50, lambda= 5)
  [1] 1.967673e-32
```

However when I get the p-value:

```
> 1-ppois(50, lambda= 5)
  [1] 0
```

Obviously, the p-value is not 0. In fact it should greater than 1.967673e-32 since I'm summing a bunch of probabilities. How do I get the extra precision?

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681756/rounding-numbers-in-r-to-specified-number-of-digits/7682869) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245862/format-numbers-to-significant-figures-nicely-in-r)

Comment: Hi, I've tried prettyNum, format and signif but it always comes out 0!

Comment: You can't get a p-value smaller than 2.2e-16. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970705/why-cant-i-get-a-p-value-smaller-than-2-2e-16

Comment: @Chargaff, have you actually read the answer to the question you linked there?  It directly contradicts your statement ...

Comment: @BenBolker. Yes your right, I always (wrongly) assumed that 2.2e-16 was the smalest p-val R could give. -1 for not reading entire post...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704365/pchisq-increase-decimal-accurancy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `lower.tail=FALSE`:

```
ppois(50, lambda= 5, lower.tail=FALSE)
## [1] 2.133862e-33
```

Asking R to compute the upper tail is much more accurate than computing the lower tail and subtracting it from 1: given the inherent limitations of floating point precision, R can't distinguish (1-`eps`) from 1 for values of `eps` less than `.Machine$double.neg.eps`, typically around 10^{-16} (see `?.Machine`).

This issue is discussed in `?ppois`:

> Setting ‘lower.tail = FALSE’ allows to get much more precise
>        results when the default, ‘lower.tail = TRUE’ would return 1, see
>        the example below.

Note also that your comment about the value needing to be greater than `dpois(50, lambda=5)` is not quite right; `ppois(x,...,lower.tail=FALSE)` gives the probability that the random variable is *greater than* `x`, as you can see (for example) by seeing that `ppois(0,...,lower.tail=FALSE)` is not exactly 1, or:

```
dpois(50,lambda=5) + ppois(50,lambda=5,lower.tail=FALSE)
## [1] 2.181059e-32
ppois(49,lambda=5,lower.tail=FALSE)
## [1] 2.181059e-32
```

Comment: Hi, perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks also for your comment on p-value. It looks like to calculate a pvalue if my obs is x, I would need dpois(x, lambda) + ppois(x, lambda, lower.tail = FALSE) or equivalent, ppois(x -1 lambda, lower.tail = FALSE).